# Translation of idiom "Not to put too fine a point on it"

Tags: идиомы

Какая самая близкая русская идиома?

Edit: including definitions and usage examples from [Idioms by The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/not+to+put+too+fine+a+point+on+it).

> *Figurative: a phrase introducing a fine or important point, apologetically*.
> Rachel: Not to put too fine a point on it, Mary, but you're still acting a little rude to Tom.
> Mary: I'm sorry, but that's the way I feel.

> John: I think, not to put too fine a point on it, you ought to do exactly as you are told.
> Andy: And I think you ought to mind your own business.

---

> *To mean exactly what is said*:  
Her performance, not to put too fine a point on it, was terrible.

Comment: Could you please provide the definition of the idiom and a usage sample for those not familiar with it? Thanks!

Comment: Some definitions and usage examples are here: http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/not+to+put+too+fine+a+point+on+it

Comment: could you please copy the relevant parts into the post body? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not to put too fine a point on it — грубо говоря, если уж начистоту, если уж называть вещи своими именами,сказать по правде.

something that you say when you are going *to say exactly what you mean, even if other people may not like it*.

Answer (score 3):

The idiom means "to put it bluntly" and can be translated into Russian using:

> - **Если говорить начистоту**, то строительство горки - дело довольно дорогостоящее и хлопотное.
> - **Называя вещи своими именами**, священник ― апологет телегонии, нанес ребенку тяжелейшую психологическую травму.
> - Или, **говоря прямо**, вы не двинете свой отряд на выручку?
> - **Откровенно говоря**, Пазульский, вы совсем не умеете говорить.

etc.

Comment: Мне кажется, что "to put it bluntly" не выражает оттенок сарказма, присущий в этой идиоме.

Comment: There's another one - без обиняков. Говоря/выражаясь без обиняков, ... but this is rarely used these days. To make it sound more apologetically, perhaps - честно говоря, откровенно говоря.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the answers are exactly correct, because the given definitions of the idiom given in the question

> To mean exactly what is said

and in one of the answers

> The idiom means "to put it bluntly"

Are incorrect. This is the definition given in the dictionary linked to in the question:

> Not to belabor the point or dwell on a minor detail. Said to excuse oneself for doing exactly that.

Some translations for this phrase into Russian that I could think of:

- Не хочу придираться к мелочам, но...
- Не хотел вдаваться в тонкости, но...
- Не хочу быть занудой/занудствовать, но...